# Odd infinite triangle shadow based on two vertices

Tags: vertices

[image: As you can see, this triangle shadow lays on top of solid mesh and only connects with two vertices, those being the one on the left and the one on the bottom which is not visible. The one on the right is not a vertex and, while moving the camera around the mesh, appears to extend downward forever. I have tried recalculating normals for the two vertices which did not fix the issue.]
This triangle shadow lays awkwardly above the mesh, where its only actual vertices are the leftmost and bottom vertex, which is not visible in the image as the triangle shadow disappears from that angle. Recalculating any variety of normals does nothing.

Comment: could you please share your file? so I can take a look at it